# SoapUI Automated OAuth2 token retrieval issue

Tags: automation, soapui, access-token, oauth-2.0

I'm a new user with SoapUI, but I feel like this process should be easy. I've read all of the documentation I can find on this matter but I can't seem to get around this.

The issue:
I am working on load testing a website for a customer, this will involve creating 1000 accounts and navigating through a course signup process. I've managed to create test cases that step through the creation process for a new user, upon creating the new user the website automatically does an OAuth2 process and redirects the user to their profile. The way this process flows is: account created > credentials sent to a token URI in the REQUEST > RESPONSE kicks back an access token > token is used to grab credentials and redirect user to profile.

I have successfully extracted the token as a variable and stored it to the local test case, however this is where I get stuck. The only way I am able to retrieve the user profile is by manually pasting the access token into the OAuth2 access token field in SoapUI, then running the test case. Since I have to do this with 1000 accounts, this is obviously not an effective method.

I've attempted to grab ElementIDs of the login page/user creation page using the automated access token script editor, but all of these fields are located in a separate .js script, therefore the ElementID doesn't exist in SoapUI.

Am I going about this wrong, or is there someway this can be done? I'm not looking for anyone to write my code, merely explain this process if I'm understanding it incorrectly.

Comment: Have you seen this documentation? https://www.soapui.org/oauth2/automating-access-token-retrieval.html

Comment: I have Rao. The problem I'm having there is that the elements I am looking for are in a separate .js script that does not appear in the RESPONSE in SoapUI.

Comment: @Andrew I've never used this in *SOAPUI*, so I'm could be wrong, however here is my guess: Despite the fact that your elements are in a different `.js` could be possible that you can access the objects since are loaded in the global context? Or are they private members of the other `.js` file? I don't know how to *SOAPUI* provide a js context for this so maybe this is not even possible.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to bypass the OAuth2 Authentication method by creating a Groovy Script that grabs the "Set-Cookie" header from the token call then adds the cookie to each call afterwards.

This method appears to have solved the issue!

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToStringMap

def getcookie = context.testCase.testSteps["Token"].testRequest.response.responseHeaders["Set-Cookie"][0]

def headers = new StringToStringMap()
headers.put('Cookie', getcookie)

testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('Get User').testRequest.setRequestHeaders(headers)
```